# File system permission error when installing Ruby using RVM on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I am currently unable to run rvm install through Ubuntu and I have an idea as to why, but have no idea how to fix it.

Here's what's happening

```sh
~$ rvm install 2.6.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/20.04/x86_64/ruby-2.6.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/rvm/log/1609714241_ruby-2.6.1’: Permission denied
tee: /usr/share/rvm/log/1609714241_ruby-2.6.1/update_system.log: No such file or directory
Updating system....
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.6.1',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1609714241_ruby-2.6.1/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

I ended up changing my ability to edit the directory
`/log/`
and I am now being shown `There was an error(23). Failed download There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.`

when I attempt to install

Comment: How did you install rvm? The file system location in your error doesn't appear to be a standard one mentioned in the installation docs. My best guess so far is that something went wrong installing rvm, and you will need to remove it and reinstall correctly. https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common                                                                   sudo -E apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm                                                         sudo apt-get update                                                                                               
sudo apt-get install rvm                                                                                                      source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh              -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flatiron-school/dotfiles/master/rvm-shell-script >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: I don't know how rvm in Ubuntu is setup, but it seems like it's a system level install and you would need to add users to an rvm group for its use. https://rvm.io/rvm/install#1-download-and-run-the-rvm-installation-script

Comment: @ScottSwezey is right here. The `apt-get` package is most likely broken (quite common) and you should follow the bash script provided by the author instead.

Comment: Try `rvmsudo` command

Comment: So I allowed myself permissions to modify the log directory, but now I'm getting a failed download error and It's not able to create a new directory. If the apt-get package is broken how am I to delete it before attempting to re-install?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to add my Ubuntu user to rvm group using `rvm group add rvm "$USER"`

Issue resolved